# How to restrict android app to 64 bit platform download on google play

Tags: android, 64-bit, android-app-bundle

I have an app that works only in 64 bit configuration.
I've put in the following in the abi filters

```
splits{
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

But when I uploaded the app for alpha track I saw this :

[image]

How do I make sure my app is not available for download for something other than 64 bit device?

Comment: Which Gradle version did you use?

Comment: The splits do not apply to bundle. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54100434/192373

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to exclude these builds?

"exclude
Specifies a comma-separated list of ABIs that Gradle should not generate separate APKs for. Use exclude if you want to generate APKs for most ABIs, but need to exclude a few ABIs that your app doesn't support."

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits

Answer (score 0):

Set `universalApk false`, it will build one APK for each platform;
then just upload the `arm64-v8a` package (`x86_64` is irrelevant).

Comment: i'm not uploading an APK, i'm uploading a bundle, the universal apk is for internal testing purposes